# Concurrent writing to a file with c#

Tags: c#, concurrency, io

I have an application that is writing to a file concurrently

When it runs to the end, it should be about 100k lines. Right now it I will get the message after 10k records written.

**Below is the Error:**

> System.IO.__Error.Void WinIOError(Int32, System.String) - The process cannot access the file 'C:\Temp\xxx.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Code:

```
public class FileExport
{
    private object lockPathObject = new object();
    private object lockACLbject = new object();
    static string pathHeader = "ScanDate,Path,IsDirectory,Files,Size,Owner,Accessed," +
        "Created,Modified,sourcetype";
    static string aclHeader = "ScanDate,Path,Trustee,Permissions,AccessType,Inherit," + 
        "SID,sourcetype";
    static string sourceType = "EUSFileservice";

    private static NamedReaderWriterLockSlim<string> locker = 
        new NamedReaderWriterLockSlim<string>();

    public void ExportPath(IEnumerable<PathInfo> paths, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            // lock (lockPathObject)
            using (locker.LockWrite(filename))
            {
                using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(filename))
                {
                    if (w.BaseStream.Position == 0)
                        w.WriteLine(pathHeader);
                    foreach (PathInfo path in paths)
                    {
                        if (path == null)
                            continue;

                        w.WriteLine("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\",\"{4}\"," + 
                            "\"{5}\",\"{6}\",\"{7}\",\"{8}\"", DateTime.UtcNow, 
                            path.Path, (path.IsDirectory ? 1 : 0), path.Files, 
                            path.Size, path.Owner, path.AccessDate, path.CreateDate, 
                            path.ModifiedDate, sourceType);
                    }

                    w.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogger.LogEvent(ex);
        }
        return;
    }
```

I am calling it from

```
void ProcessTasks()
{
    FileExport se = new FileExport();
    while (true)
    {
        var pathList = pathQueue.DequeueChunk(20);

        se.ExportPath(pathList, pathFileName);

        if (pathQueue.Count == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using a lock and `NamedReaderWriterLockSlim` with the same results. Any suggestions?

**Update:**
The error is happenning at:

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(filename))
```

Stacktrace

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
   at System.IO.File.AppendText(String path)
```

Comment: What line does it crash on? Comment out the try/catch and see where is has an issue

Comment: Is it on windows environment? Are there multiple processes running?

Comment: Shouldn't `private object lockPathObject` be static when you are trying to use a lock?

Comment: @mohammedlok No, it just needs to be the same shared instance: [Lock Statement C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

Comment: @mohammedlok.  It is a windows environment.  It is only running a single process at this time

Comment: You still have not told us the exact type of the exception that is being thrown.  It is probably not going to make much difference, but still, you should be providing such fundamental information right from the start, without having to be asked for it one piece at a time.

Comment: This is a strange problem; it should not be happening as far as I can tell. Try forcing a full garbage collection after closing the stream and before releasing the lock.  Not that you would want that as a solution, but it could help us learn something more about the problem.

Comment: How many threads are trying to access your method `void ProcessTasks()`? When I made multiple threads call the method `void ProcessTasks()` while using `private object lockPathObject = new object();`  I ran into exactly the same error. Changing the `lockPathObject` to static resolved the error.

Comment: The lock has to be `static` here since it is protecting something static.

Comment: @mohammedlok. I am  using a static variable locker.   Also when I use the other lock I am creating a new instance.  So I don't need a statice variable